# fail to validate user input in bootstrap modal by alert message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modal-dialog

I'm able to validate user form in normal page without using modal, the alert is able to pop up if submit the form with empty text field.

Now I'm trying to make the form inside a modal and try to validate it but the validation does not show up and insert the blank data to database.

Here is the partial code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form method="POST" >

            <p>EventTitle : 
            <input type="text"  name="eTitle" id="eTitle" placeholder="Say something about this image...">
            </p>

            <script type= "text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#createEvent').click(function(){  

            var event_Title = $('#eTitle').val();
            if(event_Title =='')
            {
                alert("Title cannot be empty");
                return false;
            }

            });  

            });  
            </script>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="createEvent" id="createEvent" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: May or may not be related, but your HTML is invalid

Comment: @PatrickQ what do u mean by " invalid "?

Comment: *"but the validation does not show up and insert the blank data to database"* - This was tagged as php but no code for it and you mention a database; same thing here.

Comment: `<input type="submit"` you most likely need to use a button here, and not an input. Look at your developer console and check for errors on php and the database stuff.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to say it any other way. Your HTML is not valid.  Your tags are not in the correct order.

Comment: Ok, i will remove the php tag.

Comment: By the way, my code for inserting into database is fine, just if i put the form into the modal, the validation does not working.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you can use the built in HTML required attribute for validating empty input.

Ex: `<input type="text"  name="eTitle" id="eTitle" placeholder="Say something about this image..." required />`

Otherwise you could try to use `if (!event_Title.length > 0) {...}`

One more advice, I recommend removing the javascript from inside the html code and put it on the bottom of the file or in an external file.

Hope this helps, feel free to reach out if this does not work.